# Github-action for a particular folder

Tags: github-actions

I have a `Github` repo with structure as shown below

```
├── packages
│   ├── packageA
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   ├── packageB
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
│   ├── packageC
│   │   ├── src
│   │   ├── .eslintrc.json
│   │   ├── jest.config.ts
│   │   ├── package.json
├── .gitignore
└── README.md
```

Then there are branches branches like `dev/packageA`,`dev/packageB` so on.

Developer(s) will work only on `packageA` in branch `dev/packageA`, only on `packageB` in branch `dev/packageB`.

So, whenever a push is done to `dev/packageA`, the 'npm test `and 'npm run lint` should only be run on `packageA` folder (the tests & lint config are already available in that folder).

Is there a way to set this up? Currently I know to set this up for the whole repo.

```
name: Pre checks (eslint, test coverage)
on:
  push:
    branches: #all branches except master
      - "**"        # matches every branch
      - '!master'   # excludes master
jobs:
  test:
    name: Lint the source code   
    env:
      working-directory: ./
    steps:
      uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          token: ${{ secrets.PAT || secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: npm ci
        working-directory: ./
      - name: Lint
        run: npm run lint
        working-directory: ./
      - name: Test
        run: npm test
        working-directory: ./
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the github branch name. You can do that by:

```
- name: Get branch name
  run: echo "branch=${GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/dev/}}" >> $GITHUB_OUTPUT
  id: get_branch_name
```

You can access the above as `${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}` in your steps below as:

```
- name: Install dependencies
  run: npm ci
  working-directory: ./${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}/
- name: Lint
  run: npm run lint
  working-directory: ./${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}/
- name: Test
  run: npm test
  working-directory: ./${{ steps.get_branch_name.outputs.branch }}/
```

---

Refer https://docs.github.com/en/actions/learn-github-actions/variables#default-environment-variables for more details.

Comment: What is `${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/dev/}`? If you can provide some reference to documentation, I can read it myself. Thanks.

Comment: @moys Updated my answer with reference. Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Thanks it is clear now. If my branches are for example `create/packageA`, `develop/packageA`, `feature/packageA` (I know this is not good practice but we are here). I should use `${{GITHUB_HEAD_REF:-${GITHUB_REF#refs/heads/}}##*/}` right?

Comment: Yes, correct. But yeah, definitely not a good practice.